Troubleshooting w/o schmatic failed (flashing LED) board - looking for help in component ID

Any ideas what this component marked RSFF might be?

It looks like an unshielded drum type inductor with shrink tube over it.
Here is one with similar markings from here:

Probably there will be a designator on the PCB that is something like L1. It is unlikely to be faulty- and if it was it would likely exhibit visible or otherwise detectable sequelae such as charring or melted shrink tube.
